# Authorizing access to Log Viewer with token

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, middleware, log-viewer

I'm trying to Authorize access to Log Viewer, I'm using laravel to build API and JWT to generate token and spatie Package for Roles and Permissions.

I created this middleware:

```
    {
        if (Auth::check() && Auth::user()->hasPermissionTo('view-logs')) {
            return $next($request);
        }

        abort(401, 'Unauthorised');
    }
```

and publish log-viewer-views by this command:
`php artisan vendor:publish --tag=log-viewer-views`

in the blade file:

```
<!-- Global LogViewer Object -->
<script>
    window.LogViewer = @json($logViewerScriptVariables);

    // Add additional headers for LogViewer requests like so:
    var token = localStorage.getItem('Authorization');
    window.LogViewer.headers['Authorization'] ='Bearer ' + token;

</script>
```

but the middleware can't see the user is Auth it's always return 401 UNAUTHORIZED

I thing the blade didn't send the token

Set the token manually in local storage and Debug each step